# C DLL doesn't load in C#

Tags: c#, c, interop

I have a simple C DLL (not COM). I have also a C# 2.0 application that runs it (dllimport). The dll is placed in the exe of the application. I know that the dll is ok and also that my application that calls it success reading it, but when I move them to another computer it says that it can load the dll.

The error : "Unable to load the dll name.dll . This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect."

I used visual studio 2005 to create the dll. The targer computer is a side by side one.
When I took the folder of the side by side contains the CRT it didn't run.
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error message or exception? What exactly does it say?

Comment: "Unable to load the dll name.dll . This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect."

Comment: You should change the title to "C DLL doesn't load in C#". I thought you were trying to load a C# DLL into C!

Comment: What compiler/linker are you using for the C dll? Which version of the CRT are you using in the dll?

Comment: Using visual studio 2005. CRT ?

Comment: the version of the CRT 6.1.98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a lot from the comments people wrote and they are right. I used : Dependency Walker tool and process moniter and process explorer. I had a prblem of not detecting the right msvr80 at runtime by my application. 
I instaalled destributable package af VC++ amd didn't help.
The answear was in another discussion here and it [Side-by-side configuration error (Microsoft.VC80.CRT v8.0.50608.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420629/side-by-side-configuration-error-microsoft-vc80-crt-v8-0-50608-0)
It was a problem of security update : Microsoft.VC80.CRT v8.0.50727.4053 (Installed via a security update).

Answer (score 4):

The C Dll can have various dependencies. Try using Dependency Walker tool to determine if there are any of them.

Comment: I used the dpendency walker and found the dll depends are found.
I used visual studio 2005 to create the dll. The targer computer is a side by side one. When I took the folder of the side by side contains the CRT it didn't run. Thanks

Comment: fwiw, some guy ported DependencyWalker into modern-day C#, and I just used it to successfully diagnose an issue of this type: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Windows may have detected a side-by-side version configuration issue with your application.

For example, the C dll will usually be compiled against a particular version of the Microsoft C runtime library , which might not be installed on your second computer. It also doesn't have to be the C runtime library, it may be some other library.

How to diagnose it?

Check out this article, http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2006/04/14/576314.aspx for a starting point, although no guarantees.

Comment: I used visual studio 2005 to create the dll. The targer computer is a side by side one. When I took the folder of the side by side contains the CRT it didn't run. Thanks